# How can I save EditText input as class attribute in Kotlin/AndroidStudio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have a class called Symptomz, which has the attribute "notes" as a string and "intensity" as an int. I would like to link the information received on user input of EditText to become the data stored in the attribute "notes" and the "intensity" attribute to contain information received from the seekbar.

```
open class Symptomz(notes:String, intensity:Int) {
var intensity:int
var notes:String

init{
    this.notes = notes
    this.intensity = intensity
}
public override fun toString():String {
    return notes
}
```

Here is the XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/addNotesToSymptom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="181dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="start|top"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBox2" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBarSymptomIntensity"
    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.SeekBar"
    android:layout_width="256dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="61dp"

    android:layout_marginEnd="124dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:filterTouchesWhenObscured="false"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:indeterminateBehavior="repeat"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="0"
    android:thumb="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/checkBox2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can link it directly, but you can access the EditText content via

```
val edit: EditText = findViewById(R.id.addNotesToSymptom);
val result : String = edit.getText().toString();
```

Just use the EditText directly whenever you need it :)